# Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : undefined exports: ... Error: package or namespace load failed

Tags: r, namespaces, ggplot2

I recently updated R to the latest version (R version 3.1.1) and now I can´t run load packages. In the case of ggplot2, the error message after running library("ggplot2") is

```
    *Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) :   
  undefined exports: ContinuousRange, DiscreteRange, abs_area, alpha, area_pal, as.trans, asn_trans, atanh_trans, boxcox_trans, brewer_pal, cbreaks, censor, col2hcl, comma, comma_format, cscale, date_breaks, date_format, date_trans, dichromat_pal, discard, div_gradient_pal, dollar, dollar_format, dscale, exp_trans, expand_range, extended_breaks, format_format, fullseq, gradient_n_pal, grey_pal, hue_pal, identity_pal, identity_trans, is.trans, linetype_pal, log10_trans, log1p_trans, log2_trans, log_breaks, log_trans, logit_trans, manual_pal, math_format, muted, parse_format, percent, percent_format, pretty_breaks, probability_trans, probit_trans, reciprocal_trans, rescale, rescale_max, rescale_mid, rescale_none, rescale_pal, reverse_trans, scientific, scientific_format, seq_gradient_pal, shape_pal, show_col, sqrt_trans, squish, squish_infinite, time_trans, trans_breaks, trans_format, trans_new, trans_range, zero_range  

Además: Mensajes de aviso perdidos  
S3 methods 'fullseq.Date', 'fullseq.POSIXt', 'fullseq.numeric', 'print.trans' were declared in NAMESPACE but not found 
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ggplot2'*
```

For package BiodiversityR, the error message ends with

```
*Error: package or namespace load failed for 'BiodiversityR'*
```

I've tried several tricks like re-installing, updating, loading in previous R versions, including 32-bit versions.

```
sessionInfo:  
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Mexico.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Mexico.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Mexico.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Mexico.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] tcltk     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] xtable_1.7-3 reshape2_1.4 nlme_3.1-117 plyr_1.8.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4     grid_3.1.1       gtable_0.1.2
 [5] lattice_0.20-29  munsell_0.4.2    proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.11.1     
 [9] stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.1  

    packageVersion("ggplot2")
[1] '1.0.0'
```

Comment: Could you delete the `ggplot2` folder and other packages that it depends on and then reinstall it and report if this works?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, one or more of the dependend packages had to be updated.

I created a new empty library directory where I re-installed all packages and this solved the problem. Thanks!

My error was updating only ggplot2 `update.packages("ggplot2")` while I should have ran `update.packages()`.

Answer (score 0):

I often find simply retrying with require() works for some reason:
`require(BiodiversityR)`