# Error message every time I try to work with tidyverse, modelr and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio, tidyverse, modelr

I get this same error message every time I try to work with `tidyverse`, `modelr` and `dplyr`.

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
>    undefined exports: contains, ends_with, everything, last_col, matches, num_range, one_of, peek_vars, poke_vars, scoped_vars, starts_with, vars_pull, vars_rename, vars_select, vars_select_helpers, with_vars.

This is the message I get when I select `tidyverse`, but this same message comes up when I try `modelr` or `dplyr` (of course `tidyverse` is replaced by one of these two).

I reinstalled R and R-studio 3 times, uninstalled and installed all these packages and I still get this error message.

Comment: have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413109/error-in-namespaceexportns-exports-undefined-exports-error-package-or

Comment: my guess is that when you install your packages some of the installs actually fail. There may be some depedencies that need to be updated.

Comment: This is unfortunately not the case. I reinstalled all the packages and R says that all the packages are successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked. So this is not hte case.

Comment: Have you tried to delete manually all the packages in the libraries folders? Use  .libPaths() to find them all

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much!